# How to preserve midnight timestamp in R when converting from MDY-HMS to YMD-HMS

Tags: r, datetime, character, lubridate

I have a character string that gives a date and an a time stamp in the MDY-HMS format
`"12/14/23 12:00:00 AM"`

When I use the `mdy_hms` function in `lubridate` to re-format the string as YMD-HMS, the timestamp is gone.

What can be done to make sure that the midnight timestamp is preserved?

When I use the `mdy_hms` function in `lubridate` to re-format the string as YMD-HMS, the timestamp is gone.

`mdy_hms("12/14/23 12:00:00 AM")`

`"2023-12-14 UTC"`

I've tested the mdy_hms function by replace the 12 in the hour as 00 and it gives the same result, but when the timestamp portion of the string is either 12:01:00 AM or 00:01:00 AM, the timestamp is preserved.

`mdy_hms("12/14/23 12:01:00 AM")`

`"2023-12-14 00:01:00 UTC"`

`"2023-12-14 00:01:00 UTC"`

I want the output to be "2023-12-14 00:00:00 UTC"

Comment: It's just the way `POSIXct`  with 00:00 time portion gets printed by default. You can use whatever format suits you better, `lubridate::mdy_hms("12/14/23 12:00:00 AM") |> strftime("%c")` for example. Can you describe the situation where it becomes a problem? (i.e. report tables in knitted/ rendered Rmd or Quarto notebooks, ... ).

Comment: @margusl if I remove the time zone and then convert the string with as.POSIXct into a datetime, then I cannot compute the time difference with another datetime string using the difftime function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not gone. It just how the value is printed out per default.

```r
ala <- lubridate::mdy_hms("12/14/23 12:00:00 AM")
ala
#> [1] "2023-12-14 UTC"
```

Use `format()` to change it. And the computations (time difference) works properly:

```r
format(ala, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#> [1] "2023-12-14 00:00:00"

ola <- lubridate::mdy_hms("12/14/23 01:00:00 PM")

ola - ala
#> Time difference of 13 hours
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-15 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>